# Dynamically changing jqueryui accordion event handler from "click" to "mouseover"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, javascript-framework

I have a situation where I would like to be able to drag an item from a list into a target in an accordion. However, the item that I am dragging to might be in another panel (one that isn't open).

In order to facilitate this, I would like to dynamically change the accordion's event from click to mouseover once the drag starts.  After the drag is complete, I'll switch back to click.  This will let the user hover over the closed panel, causing it to open at which point they can drop the item.  Once they're done, I'd prefer that they use a click to open the panel.

Is this possible?  I've tried using the setter:

$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "event", 'mouseover' );

but it doesn't seem to actually change the event on the fly.  I found some mention that this might not be supported.  If not, does anyone know how I might do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like this was actually a bug.  Should be resolved in 1.9.

[JqueryUI bug 6740](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6740)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the setter in the element-drag event-handler. Something like the following should work:

```
$('li.draggable').mousedown(function(){

    $( "div.accordion" ).accordion( "option", "event", 'mouseover' );

}).mouseup(function(){

    $( "div.accordion" ).accordion( "option", "event", 'click' );

});
```

You'll need to tailor the selectors to your particular case. The `mousedown` event-handler will trigger when the user clicks down on the draggable element, changing the accordion's `event` setting to 'mouseover'; when the click is released, ending the drag, the accordion's `event` setting gets reverted to 'click'.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That's the easy part.  The issue I'm having is that the accordion doesn't actually seems to dynamically change its event.  I can set it, and the value changes, but the event still triggers the same way.  I've even tried setting it in firebug's command line with $( "div.accordion" ).accordion( "option", "event", 'mouseover' );
 and it doesn't work.